# Insert entire record with cursor after checking if it exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I have the following script that uses a cursor insert records into a table if they do not exist in that table.  This works but I want to modify it to insert the entire record without having to specify each field individually.  Is it possible to reference the entire record and insert it?

```
SET @Cursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT [COMPANY],[LOCATION],[id] FROM [GG].[dbo].[LOCATION]

 OPEN @Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @COMPANY, @Location, @id;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    select @numFound = count(*) FROM [GG].[dbo].[gsLocation] where company = @COMPANY and location = @Location;
    IF @numFound = 0
    BEGIN
        -- Want to be able to insert entire record instead of specifying fields
        insert into [GG].[dbo].[gsLocation] (company, Location, id) values (@COMPANY, @Location, @id)
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @COMPANY, @Location, @id;
END
```

Comment: Why cursor?????

Comment: Why use a cursor for anything, especially for something as easy as an `INSERT ... SELECT ...` ? Using a cursor is the slowest way possible to use data in a database. In this particular case it will execute 100 INSERTs for 100 rows instead of a single INSERT

Comment: It's a common best practice to specify column names on a insert. While in theory your tables might have the same columns, even the order of the columns could be different (if they are created differently, for example). IMHO you should never insert data into a table without specifying the columns. You could use a dynamic SQL query to get the column names and create your insert statement like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it a lot simpler without a cursor:

```
Insert into [GG].[dbo].[gsLocation] (COMPANY, LOCATION, id)
Select  L.COMPANY, 
        L.LOCATION, 
        L.id
From [GG].[dbo].[LOCATION] L
where not exists (Select * From [GG].[dbo].[gsLocation] where company = L.COMPANY and location = L.LOCATION)
```

It's always a good practice to specify the name of the columns.

Comment: You do NOT need to use TOP inside of an EXISTS expression - the engine got smart about that years ago. Nor do you need to use a literal - "*" works just as well and is usually less confusing to the inexperienced.

Comment: Interesting, I created the habit of using top 1 years ago. It's one of those things you never though about. Updated the answer with your recommendation.

Comment: Either `WHERE NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN gsLocation on ... where gsLocation.company is NULL`

Comment: Aside: Since the _select list_ is ignored for an `exists` query (`select 666 where exists ( select 1 / 0 from sys.columns );`) and there are people who were flogged into NEVER USING * in a query, I use [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_is_42) as a placeholder to remind me that I thought about what to select and that nothing was needed.